# Linux, kitty не запускается из за ошибки

Tags: linux, bash

```
$ kitty
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/kitty/__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/kitty/kitty/entry_points.py", line 203, in main
    from kitty.main import main as kitty_main
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/kitty/kitty/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .borders import load_borders_program
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/kitty/kitty/borders.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .fast_data_types import (
ImportError: libcrypto.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Как я понял ошибка в том, что питон не может найти какой то модуль, но вот как это фиксить...

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libcrypto.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any

Comment: Вы вручную устанавливали? Если да, то установите пакет с помощью пакетного менеджера вашей системы. Если нет, то это, вероятно, баг мэйнтэйнера. См. https://www.reddit.com/r/KittyTerminal/comments/ymdjgc/cant_load_after_syu_arch_importerror_libcryptoso3/.